# Recoding values, by removing extra chars

Tags: r, grepl

Most of the values in a variable of my dataset has two extra characters at the end to reprensent the number of visits from the subject, like id_0, or id_24, or id_48... Like in the below:

```
  subjectid                   le                 lt
1  CC0005_0                 4022.5             133.8
2  CC0196_0                 4099.6             190.7
3  CC0197_0                 5518.1             595.0
4  CC0202_48                 6604.3             358.2
5  CC0212_0                 7047.3             427.8
6  CC0239_24                 4935.2             215.7
```

My first thought was to use apply and grepl together, but I couldn't go past:`grepl("*_0", mydata$subjectid)`, this seems to catch the correct items, but how to rename them?

- How can I get rid of "_0" without changing the ones that have "_24" or "_48"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match the `_` followed by 0 at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df1$subjectid <- sub("_0$", "", df1$subjectid)
df1$subjectid
#[1] "CC0005"    "CC0196"    "CC0197"    "CC0202_48" "CC0212"    "CC0239_24"
```